# Handling failure when deleting a directory in C#

Tags: c#

I tried to delete directory by:

```
dir1.Delete(true);
```

One file is open from that directory so exception occoured but all the files present in the directory are also deleted.

How is it possible idealy if exception occoured then the files in the directory should remains same?

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: You could maybe create a temporary directory and move the files into it. If a file is open in cannot be moved and will cause an error, but you still have the files and can move them back.

If all goes well you should be able to delete the new directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Transactionscope class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
try
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        dir1.Delete(true);
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //deleteion failed
}
```